# unable to set value of latency_timer register of PCI configuration space

Tags: linux, pci, pci-e

I am trying to set latency timer value of my Intel PCI card using following command

```
sudo setpci -d '8086:0100' latency_timer=01
```

But when I read the value of this register back it is unchanged and shows previous value.

I am using following command to display value of the register

```
sudo setpci -d '8086:0100' latency_timer
```

Can anybody tell why I'm unable to change value of latency timer?

I'm using a `Linux` machine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that you have more than one PCI devices or more than one functions with identical `vid:did`.

Find out the location of your PCI device using `sudo lspci`, then use

```
sudo setpci -s bus:slot.func ...
```

instead of

```
sudo setpci -d vid:did ...
```